How to set Civilization 6 to high resolution on iPad?
There used to be a method to set Civ6 to Retina resolution on iPad, similar to how it's done on Mac (Civilization VI Resolution on Mac Retina Display).
It required iExplorer software to edit a GraphicsOptions.txt configuration file, but after the retirement of iTunes, iExplorer no longer works.
Is there a method to edit GraphicsOptions.txt that works after 2024?

At the time of writing, it seems to have been solved out of box.
After a fresh install, Civ6 on iPad Pro from the beginning has Retina 1 in AppOptions.txt and the correct resolution in GraphicsOptions.txt.
App's configuration files can be seen in Finder on a connected Mac, if the iPad and Mac are updated to a compatible OS versions.
I was fooled by some bitmaps in the UI that indeed were not up to Retina, likely because they never existed in Retina-ready resolution. I don't expect Firaxis to create Retina assets, as it's much more work than the default configuration.
The rest of the game is crisp and clear.
